# Is it possible to see if a string contains [multiple] dictionary words?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Currently, I have a table of words (~250k) and I want to be able to detect if a User's [new] P/W contains zero, one, or more dictionary words defined within the table. I'd thought that the comparison below would send an error message with only 1 dictionary word but an example P/W string (has at least 4 words excluding Be-My) "ThisWillBeMyPassPhrase2!1!" still gets caught. Any ideas how to resolve this issue?

'''
open word_list;
loop
fetch word_list into word_rec;
exit when word_list%notfound;

```
if instr(nls_lower(password),nls_lower(word_rec.word)) = 1 then
  raise_application_error(-20003, 'New password should have only ONE word or be a Passphrase');
end if;
```

end loop;
'''

error msg: ORA-20003: New password should have only ONE word or be a Passphrase
28003. 00000 -  "password verification for the specified password failed"
*Cause:    The new password did not meet the necessary complexity

Answer (score 0):

Your current pseudo-code:

```
for i := 1 to dictionary_size do 
  if dictionary_word(i) is in candidate_password exactly 1 time then 
    stop the "if" and the "for" and raise app error;
  end if; 
end for;
```

Whereas it should be:

```
counter := 0;
for i := 1 to dictionary_size do
  if dictionary_word(i) is in candidate_password exactly 1 time then
    counter := counter + 1;
  end if;
end for;
if counter = 1 then
  raise app error;
end if;
```

Answer (score 0):

Operating on a row set by looping over it like this is not a good idea. Row-by-row is slow-by-slow. You're better off doing this in a single step entirely in SQL. Something like:

```
select count(*) from (
    select dt.word 
      from dictionary_table dt
     where instr( lower( dt.word ), lower( password )) > 0
     fetch first 2 rows only
)
```

The `fetch first 2 rows only` is there because you only care if there exists a passphrase, you don't care if there are 2 or 7 words in it. So once you find two matching words,  you know you have a passphrase and can stop.